# DataTable change comma separator

Tags: pentaho

Hi I'm using Pentaho CE,
I'd like to know where I can chage the DataTable underlying the TableComponent propertis such as the thousand separator in order to show a point instead of default comma as thousand separator.

This is the oLanguage sInfoThounsand properties..

OK, I'm using the oLanguage in my table definition in the following way.

"oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "cerca",
        "sInfoThousands": "."
    },

But I have a problem, Why the propery sSearch is set and sInfoThousand doesn't change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataTable is accessible using the dataTable property on the table component object.